# Qt Threading synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Consider the the following situation:

I have a QThread that constantly modifies a variable (let's call it `counter`) and a QTimer that periodically reads `counter`. I know that I have to synchronize variables that might be modified by multiple threads at the same time but - do I need synchronization in this case as well, when there is only one thread reading and one thread writing a variable?

Comment: Yes - but synchronization can be achieved in several different ways. Atomic variables would seem like a sensible, lock-free solution for your situation.

Comment: @KerrekSB I believe that it is "considered" safe nowadays to use a plain `int` as an atomic variable, because modern compilers typically implement increments/decrements/reads of `int`s in a single clock cycle - do you know if that's correct?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I don't think so

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: That has nothing to do with "now", or "considered", or even "clock cycle" (heaven forbid). It's true that it's very easy to implement atomics on x86 architectures, but there are a ton of other things you need to consider. Just because it's spelled `std::atomic<int>` doesn't mean that it's expensive, difficult or somehow not suitable for home use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you always need synchronisation — if for no other reason than that the standard says that your program has undefined behaviour if there is a data race.

You can either synchronize with a mutex that guards the counter variable, which I suppose is the "traditional" way, or you can use an `std::atomic<int>` variable for your counter, which you can access without creating a data race.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Please check my comment to ddriver's answer :)

Answer (score 4):

The scenario you describe isn't safe, you will still need synchronization. There are several classes in Qt that can help you with that, via a locking or a lock-free mechanism.

Take a peek at QMutex, QReadWriteLock, QSemaphore, QWaitCondition, QFuture, QFutureWatcher, QAtomicInt and QAtomicPointer. Plus you have `std::atomic<T>` in C++11.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I just wonder, what might break if a variable is written and read at the same time. If a variable is written at the same time by two threads, the variable might have bad values afterwards, so synchronization is needed. I just can't figure out what bad things might happen in my scenario. Can you give some examples?

Comment: I know at first glance there are plenty of cases where this should be perfectly safe. For example, you won't read a result before you have received a signal that its calculation is done. In that case it is safe. But you can never know in more complex scenarios. You could just as well read a value while it is being in the middle of a non-atomic operation and get garbage. Then there are cache lines and so on... So better safe than sorry.

Comment: Thanks! So in my situation, I might consider it safe to not use a lock? `counter` is only modified in a "`counter++` -manner" . In my scenario, synchronization is probably hard, but I will open another question for it.

Comment: It is a little hard to give an answer considering there is nothing known about your scenario. Opening another question with more code would be a good idea.

Comment: I'd never heard of `std::atomic<int>`. +1 for that reference.

Comment: @ddriver: I'll go for that.

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843600/qt-synchronization-impossible-here

Answer (score 2):

Protect your `counter` variable with a [QReadWriteLock](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qreadwritelock.html). When you're editing the `counter` variable in your thread(s), have them lock it with a [QWriteLocker](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwritelocker.html), which will lock out any other attempts to write OR read. When your main thread checks the value of `counter`, lock it with a [QReadLocker](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qreadlocker.html), which will only lock if a write lock is current active.