# Qt synchronization impossible here?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Consider the following situation:

```
class SomeClass : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
private:
    unsigned long long someVar;

public:
    unsigned long long getSomeVar(){
        return someVar;
    void threadFunc();
}
```

`threadFunc()` will be invoked in a new thread (you guessed it), and it will look like this:

```
void SomeClass::threadFunc()
{
  ++someVar;
  // Do stuff...
}
```

Now, in another thread, I want to read `someVar`. I do so by calling `getSomeVar()`. However, synchronization is needed. How do I do that? For the thread that posesses `somevar`, synchronization is not hard. It'll just be

```
void SomeClass::threadFunc()
{
  mut.lock();
  ++someVar;
  mut.unlock();
  // Do stuff...
}
```

with a `QMutex mut` added in the class declaration. But how do I synchronize `getSomeVar()` ? I can't just say:

```
unsigned long long getSomeVar(){
  mut.lock();
  return someVar;
  mut.unlock();
}
```

`mut.unlock()` will never be called because of the `return`-statement before.

I know that usually such conflicts are avoided by writing...

```
unsigned long long getSomeVar(){
  QMutex mut;
  // mut-constructor calls mut.lock()
  return someVar;
  // mut-destructor calls mut.unlock()
}
```

... but in this case, I need the mutex to be the same inside `getSomeVar()` and `threadFunc()`. I tried

```
unsigned long long getSomeVar(){
  // constructing mutex from mut (which is the class' mutex)
  QMutex mutex(mut);
  // mutex-constructor calls mut.lock()
  return someVar;
  // mutex-destructor calls mut.unlock()
}
```

but the copy-constructor of mutex is private.

What can I do here?

Comment: In many situations in Qt, you can avoid the need for explicit synchronization with the use of signals and slots. Don't know if it would cause too much churn in your specific use.

Comment: Signals and slots are definitely the nicer way to do this, but they also affect performance heavily if I fire an event every time I change `someVar`. So I didn't really want signals and slots.

Comment: @MaxBeikirch - people often confuse signals and slot for basic functions, signals and slots are for signaling, they are not intended to be fired in tight performance loops. Not only is it impossible to inline them, but the overhead is quite tremendous, not to mention inter-thread connections are queued and awfully slow. You would use the connection once when you run your task and once when the task is completed, maybe also periodically to get the progress, but most certainly you won't rely on signals and slots to transfer lots of data or run in tight loops.

Comment: I thought so, periodically firing an event was also something I considered, but then I figured out that a polling `QTimer` would do the job quite well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [QMutexLocker](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmutexlocker.html)

```
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mut);
    ...
}

// Goes out of scope, unlocks the mutex in its destructor
```

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the *mutex* with the *lock*: There's only one mutex per guardable variable, but there may be many attempts to lock it!

You need a separate lock class, of which you have one instance *per thread*:

```
struct Lock
{
    QMutex & m_;
    Lock(QMutex & m) : m_(m) { m_.lock(); }
    ~Lock() { m_.unlock();}
};
```

Usage:

```
QMutex mutex;

void thread_function()
{
    Lock lk(mut);
    critical_operation();
}   // unlocks "mutex" as if by magic
```

Qt probably already provides such a class for your. (The standard library does so, too: for `std::mutex` you have `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`.)

Comment: @MaxBeikirch: Whichever you find most useful. I don't really care, if that makes it easier...

Comment: I'll go for Chris answer then as he was some seconds earlier.

Comment: @MaxBeikirch: ... and that's what I get for suggesting the answer "you find most useful" :-)

Comment: They are both useful, that's the problem :D

Comment: @MaxBeikirch: Haha, OK, you meant it as a tie breaker, that's cool. There's been plenty of discussion on this website about "speed answering" (and the encouragement thereof), and I was just thinking about that and amused. Never mind!